# converting varchar to number while passing to IN clause

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, stored-procedures, plsql

I am really stuck here..

Given below is the miniature of what I am trying to achieve.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
rajesh varchar2(20);
x number(10);
begin
select wm_concat(stocks_id) into rajesh from users_stocks where users_id=28800;
select count(*) into x from users_stocks where stocks_id in(rajesh); 
dbms_output.put_line(x);
end;
/
```

Here is the error report

```
Error report:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 6
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The data type defined for stocks_id is number, and `rajesh` here is `varchar2`, that is why is this error is getting generated. I need some way by which rajesh comes as number to `IN` clause. 
As I stated this is just miniature I can not do something like this

```
select count(*) into x from users_stocks where stocks_id in(select some column from someTable);
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to use "execute immediate" and concatenation the contents of the variable into the query string.

Comment: Why can't you do what you write at the end?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go down this route (be aware there's a limit of 4000 values per `IN`, and all of the individual SQL statements are going to flood your shared pool, potentially causing performance problems), you can alter your code to use `execute immediate` and concatenate the `IN` list into the query.

You'd be better off combining the 2 queries in your code into a single query, and avoiding this completely.

Comment: +1 for combining those queries into one -- even just rewrite this as a plain-old join.